# Make or Makes within a sentence?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, subject-verb-agreement

Are both of these statements acceptable grammatically?

> Receiving homemade cupcakes *make* me feel special.
>
> Receiving homemade cupcakes *makes* me feel special.

Answer (score 1):

The formal and traditional answer is *makes*, because the subject is the singular noun phrase *receiving homemade cupcakes*.

In actual speech, and even sometimes in writing, many people say *make*, under the influence of the more recent plural noun *cupcakes*.

I would recommend saying *makes*, but be prepared to hear *make*.

Comment: I don't think this is right. Ignoring the potentially (to nns, not native speakers) distracting adjective, you're suggesting that native speakers might come out with things like *Receiving guests **make** me nervous*, or *Eating raw meat **make** you sick.* I'd say we ***never*** make that kind of mistake.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica: I don't think the adjective is irrelevant, because it separates the singular subject even further from the verb. I'm sure people do do this, though I'm hard-pressed to think of a way of searching for it. Your _raw meat_ example doesn't work, because _meat_ isn't plural.

Comment: I realised as soon as I posted the comment that my *meat* example wasn't quite right. I'd actually intended to write ***sausages***, but being such a terrible speller I bottled it and just substituted the first easy-to-spell "synonym" that came to mind. Whatever - I know you know more about linguistics in general than me, but I still find it hard to believe that many/any "normal" native speakers would get the plurality wrong in the context we're talking about here, "distracting" adjectives notwithstanding.

Comment: ...I'd have thought full-time professional linguists would long ago have identified specific aspects of syntax (in various languages, not just English) that commonly cause problems for ***non-native*** speakers, but which the actual natives ***very rarely*** get wrong. In fact, I might ask about this on SO linguistics, because it seems likely to me there could be some insights there (with different *types* of syntax error being more or less likely to affect the *native* speakers of different languages, as well as nns).